# How do I get a Word document window by name in Applescript?

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I have two Word documents open and want to close one and not the other.

I've searched all over but I'll be darned if I can figure out how to get a reference to the windows I want to close.

In a `tell application "Microsoft Word"` try block I've tried:

```
activate window "foobar.docx"

set active document to "foobar.docx"

set the active window to "foobar.docx"
```

and several others.

How do I make "foobar.docx" the active window or reference it directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go , I looked it up in the dictionary but it's not how most applications would do it so I did have to fish the dictionary  :)

where then name of the open document is Document 3

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate object document "Document3"
end tell
```

Comment: no problem, you know every app has a dictionary right ? if not goto script editor's file menu "open dictionary" then choose the app you want. :)